# Regex - script check for allowed characters

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I need to check a string and make sure that it does not contain any character outside list of given characters.

I wrote one script to test this:

```
str="$1"

regex="^[0-9a-zA-Z\,\!\-\^\`@\{\}\[\],=\(\).;\/~_|]*$"

if [[ "$str" =~ $regex ]]
then
  echo "f yeah"
else
  echo "f you"
fi
```

But it does not seem to work. And it seems to me that I am not even close.

List of allowed characters is :

> a-z A-Z 0-9 ` @ { } [ ] ^ , = ! ( ) . ; / ~ _ |

Not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: You are including backslash in the script but it is not in the list of allowed chars.

Comment: Not sure about `bash`, but in most systems, IIRC, you don't backslash-quote characters inside a bracketed character class.

Comment: Actually I pasted wrong string.

Comment: Have you tested it step by step? I mean, first `^[0-9]$`, second `^[0-9a-z]$`, and then on.. I'm unable to test it here.

Comment: BTW, in general, if you're needing to check data against allowed characters to prevent it from doing something evil, you're Doing It Wrong. Following best practices keeps data out-of-band from code, preventing attacks even if it *does* contain content that would be malicious if substituted as a substring into code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Chepner indicated, most "special" characters lose their specialness if you put them inside a range (square brackets).  Also, per [`man re_format`](http://freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=re_format):

> *To include a literal `]` in the list, make it the first character (following a possible `^`).  To include a literal `-`, make it the first or last character, or the second endpoint of a range.*

If we re-order your range to match these rules, I would expect the following to work:

```
regex='^[][a-zA-Z0-9`@{}^,=!().;/~_|]*$'
```

And if you also want a hyphen:

```
regex='^[][a-zA-Z0-9`@{}^,=!().;/~_|-]*$'
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, characters have no special meaning inside `[ ... ]` in a regular expression. You need to quote a few characters to prevent `bash` from treating them specially while defining the variable that holds the regular expression, but that is most easily done by single-quoting the string.

```
regex='^[0-9a-zA-Z,!\-^`@{}[\]=().;/~_|]*$'
```

Only the hyphen (if it is not the first or last character in the bracket expression) and the `]` (if it is not the first character) need to be escaped. For example:

```
regex='^[-0-9a-zA-Z,!^`@{}[\]=().;/~_|]*$'
regex='^[]0-9a-zA-Z,!\-^`@{}[=().;/~_|]*$'
```

are both valid.

Comment: Oops, meant to change those to single quotes.

Comment: Hm. The variant that puts `]` as the first character in the class works. I'm not sure why the others don't.

Comment: I am not sure if I am using it incorrectly, but it s not even working for 12

Comment: And I hope you are referring to `regex='^[]0-9a-zA-Z,!\-^`@{}[=().;/~_|]*$'` variant

Comment: Right. The first one (and I haven't checked the second) seems to match any string. I used `[[ foo =~ $regex ]] && echo "Match: ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"` to see what exactly matched, and it appears that it matches the empty string.

Comment: It seems, first two match everything and last one doesn't match anything :(

Comment: @chepner, your first and third regexes include a range of characters between ``\`` and `^`. Bash doesn't interpret the backslash as an "escape from  specialness" for the hyphen, it simply includes it as an end point on a range within the square bracket expression. See my answer for a working solution.

Comment: I thought I remembered you could escape the `-`, but I was obviously mistaken.